# Keep the row immediately after a date (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame which looks like this:

| ID | Record Date | Cutoff Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-31 | 1 |
| A | 2022-01-15 | 2022-01-31 | 2 |
| A | 2022-01-28 | 2022-01-31 | 3 |
| B | 2022-01-15 | 2022-01-31 | 1 |
| B | 2022-01-28 | 2022-01-31 | 2 |
| B | 2022-01-31 | 2022-01-31 | 3 |
| C | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-31 | 1 |
| C | 2022-01-27 | 2022-01-31 | 2 |
| C | 2022-02-01 | 2022-01-31 | 3 |
| C | 2022-02-03 | 2022-01-31 | 4 |
| D | 2022-06-03 | 2022-01-31 | 1 |

For each `ID`, I want to keep only 1 row, based on the following criteria:

1. If there is a row with `Record Date` == `Cutoff Date`, keep this row.
2. If all `Record Date` is before `Cutoff Date`, keep the row which is closet to `Cutoff Date`.
3. If there exist any `Record Date` after `Cutoff Date`, keep the earliest row after `Cutoff Date`.
4. If there is only 1 row for an `ID`, keep this row.

Note that `Cutoff Date` is constant for each `ID`. (I set all `Cutoff Date` identical to make it simplier).

The desired output:

| ID | Record Date | Cutoff Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-01-28 | 2022-01-31 | 3 |
| B | 2022-01-31 | 2022-01-31 | 3 |
| C | 2022-02-01 | 2022-01-31 | 3 |
| D | 2022-06-03 | 2022-01-31 | 1 |

Comment: What happens if there is a `Record Date` n days before and n days after the `Cutoff Date` - which row do you keep?

Comment: Rule #3, keep the row closest to `Record Date` and after `Cutoff Date`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can craft a sorter DataFrame based on the timedeltas and use it to select the top index:

```
s = df['Record Date'].sub(df['Cutoff Date'])

sorter = pd.concat([-s.clip(upper='0'), s.abs()], axis=1).sort_values(by=[0,1])

out = df.loc[sorter.groupby(df['ID']).head(1).sort_index().index]
```

output:

```
   ID Record Date Cutoff Date  Value
2   A  2022-01-28  2022-01-31      3
5   B  2022-01-31  2022-01-31      3
8   C  2022-02-01  2022-01-31      3
10  D  2022-06-03  2022-01-31      1
```

intermediate sorter, `0` enables the conditions 1 and 3, `1` the condition 2, and by default the 4 will be met because of `head(1)`:

```
         0        1
5   0 days   0 days
8   0 days   1 days
9   0 days   3 days
10  0 days 123 days
2   3 days   3 days
4   3 days   3 days
7   4 days   4 days
1  16 days  16 days
3  16 days  16 days
0  30 days  30 days
6  30 days  30 days
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
out = (df.loc[df['Record Date'].sub(df['Cutoff Date']).abs()
                               .groupby(df['ID']).idxmin()])
print(out)

# Output
   ID Record Date Cutoff Date  Value
2   A  2022-01-28  2022-01-31      3
5   B  2022-01-31  2022-01-31      3
8   C  2022-02-01  2022-01-31      3
10  D  2022-06-03  2022-01-31      1
```

Comment: this won't work if you want to prioritize the "after" delta vs the "before", here this will take the closest ;)